Verify User Permissions with an api call in a Spring Gateway
I have a Spring Gateway, and want to add a custom permission check while a user is logging in.
To do that, I have to make an api call to a special permission-service during log in, to theck if the user has valid permissions for the given tenant (A tenant is identified by the subdomain of the login attempt)
I am configuring the security in the SecurityConfiguration. The SecurityConfiguration is called, and log in via KeyCloak is working (Logout too)
This is my SecurityConfiguration:
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfiguration {
private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    private String issuerUri;
    
    private final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        //Just path matchers and so on.
        //I could add a filter herre to do the permission check, but that would add that check to    every request, and I want it only for the Login validation
     ...
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    ReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository registrations) {
        Mono<ClientRegistration> clientRegistration = registrations.findByRegistrationId("oidc");
    
        return clientRegistration
            .map(oidc ->
                createJwtDecoder(
                    oidc.getProviderDetails().getIssuerUri(),
                    oidc.getProviderDetails().getJwkSetUri(),
                    oidc.getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUri()
                )
            )
            .block();
    }
    
    private ReactiveJwtDecoder createJwtDecoder(String issuerUri, String jwkSetUri, String userInfoUri) {
        NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = new NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder(jwkSetUri);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getOauth2().getAudience());
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuerUri);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);
    
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);
    
        return new ReactiveJwtDecoder() {
            @Override
            public Mono<Jwt> decode(String token) throws JwtException {
                
                **//Here I would like to add the request to the permission-service**
    
                return jwtDecoder.decode(token).flatMap(jwt -> enrich(token, jwt));
            }
            private Mono<Jwt> enrich(String token, Jwt jwt) {
                if (jwt.hasClaim("given_name") && jwt.hasClaim("family_name")) {
                    return Mono.just(jwt);
                }
                // find the given user and add the name
            }
        }
    }

}

Parts of the pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Gateway</name>
    <description>Description for gateway</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
    </parent>
<properties>
        <playtika.reativefeign>4.0.3</playtika.reativefeign>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2023.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.playtika.reactivefeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-reactor-webclient</artifactId>
            <version>${playtika.reativefeign}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.playtika.reactivefeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-reactor-cloud</artifactId>
            <version>${playtika.reativefeign}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.playtika.reactivefeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-reactor-spring-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${playtika.reativefeign}</version>
        </dependency>

</project>

I tried adding a ReactiveFeignClient to enable a Request to the permission-service, to interrupt the decode Process if the user has no permission, and throw a new Mono.error(...).
My first Problem was, that after adding the ReactiveFeignClient:
package de.neonex.client;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import reactivefeign.spring.config.ReactiveFeignClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@ReactiveFeignClient(name = "permission-service")
public interface ReactiveTenantServiceClient {
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/tenants/subdomain:{subdomain}")
    Mono<Boolean> getBySubdomain(@PathVariable("subdomain") String subdomain);
}

and adding @EnableReactiveFeignClients to the App, Spring would give me an IllegalArgumentException:
Invalid value type for attribute 'factoryBeanObjectType': java.lang.String
The location of the Excpetion is not given, and remains a mystery to me.
My second Problem was that I realised that throwing in the decoding process (Directly over jwtDecoder.decode(...) did nothing. The process just continued normally.
Why is Throwing an exception in the decode step not doing anything, and whyt is my Problem with the ReactiveFeignClient?
I tried updating spring-parent and springclout versions. No changes.
Thanks for your time and help.

Add a filter as you suggested, and check the path of the request.  If it is the login path, then run the extra check, otherwise just continue with the rest of the filter chain.
